# Remove parameters being added to img tag

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have the image below and i want to remove everything after jpg (?resize=495%2C371&ssl=1)

https://i1.wp.com/atalantadigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/sampleimg.jpg?resize=495%2C371&ssl=1

I have tried:

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i', $images);

foreach ($images[0] as $image) {
 str_replace('?resize=495%2C371&ssl=1', ' ', $image);
}
```

There are a few images with these parameters being added that I need to fix. Im open to a php or javascript solution, thanks in advance!

And I searched stackoverflow and didnt find an answer.

Comment: Can we assume that there will be a space separating all attributes and that the value of any attribute won't contain a double quotes or greater/less than symbols?

Comment: `$e=explode('?',$url); echo $e[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is well-suited for the task because we can easily select all `img` tags as well as the `src` property via `img.src`.

This will remove all query strings (`?` and anything after it) from  `img` `src` urls on the page.

```
// searches for all images on page
let images = document.getElementsByTagName("img")
// for each image
for (let img of images) {
    // replace source query string with nothing
    img.src = img.src.replace(/\?.+$/, "")
}
```

Regex explanation:

> `\?`   Matches literal `?`
>
> `.+$`  Matches everything after it until end of input

The following shows the regex working:

```js
let img = new Image;
img.src = 'https://i1.wp.com/atalantadigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/sampleimg.jpg?resize=495%2C371&ssl=1';

img.src = img.src.replace(/\?.+$/, "");

console.log(img.src);
```

Answer (score 0):

if

```
var imgName = 'https://i1.wp.com/atalantadigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/sampleimg.jpg?resize=495%2C371&ssl=1'
```

then you could get what you want by

```
imgName.substring(0, imgName.indexOf('?'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this fix needs to be for any image with those params...not just that specific one.

Comment: This would work for any image. The ? is always going to be after the url, and this would take everything before the ?.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood properly, but from what I understand, you have:

- A string containing `<img src="image_url.jpg/?resize=495%2C371&ssl=1">` one or maybe multiple times.

If it's the case, this should do the trick (almost the same as you did):

```php
$images = "<img src='https://sampleimg.jpg?resize=495%2C371&ssl=1'><img src='https://sampleimg.jpg?resize=495%2C371&ssl=1'>";
preg_match_all('/img[^>]+>/i', $images, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $image) {
    echo $image;    // "<img src="image_url.jpg/?resize=495%2C371&ssl=1">"
    $image = str_replace('?resize=495%2C371&ssl=1', ' ', $image);    
    echo $image;    // "<img src="image_url.jpg">"
}
```

Hope this help you out!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the **W3 Total Cache** plugin, an option may be unchecked to avoid the creation of query strings. This option can be found by navigating to the **W3 plugin Performance tab > Browser Cache**. Within the General section of this page there is an option called **“Prevent caching of objects after settings change”**.

[image]

This option is deselected by default but if for any reason it is enabled, simply deselect it and **save your settings to prevent the creation of query strings**.

Comment: They're using Jetpack for caching but it would be awesome if it had this option.